# Dynamic content for googlebot

Tags: ajax, seo, googlebot

I have a website where depend on the location the user receive the some messages from another webmembers. So, by workflow user need to type the address to textfield and with an ajax callback he get back an answer. All Request to server going by POST. 
My question is how can i make it good for the googlebot? How index google the such websites like twitter? I have several solutions but i not sure:

1. When an user put the message with an address i generate some static page and give it for the searchrobot.
2. Public the users accounts with all messages from them.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best would be option 1 where you make messages crawlable with a static page URL and a link that points to that static URL

Comment: If i write static URL's in the robots.txt it is will be enough for the robots?

Comment: Absolutely not. The robots.txt is not a file to tell the SE which URLs to crawl - in fact it's the opposite. You should include the static URLs in the sitemap XML, but that might not be enough to get it indexed and ranked.